# What are all the namespaces used in xwpf to declare items in a document?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, xwpf

I want to delete empty pages in a word docx document, there is no solution for it yet. so I thought of using namespaces, so whenever the code doesn't find any declared item or a text in the paragraph it will delete it and the moment it finds one it stops the deletion. I don't know of any better solution to it since I am new to using poi-xwpf.

in the end I want the namespaces needed to solve this, or if there is a better approach to this problem.

Comment: The docx XML schemas are here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-docx/d0a2e301-0ff7-4e9e-9bb7-ff47070dce0a.  You could trawl through them to identify all of the namespaces used.

Comment: then what about the item declaration like txbxContent, drawing, ...etc

Comment: They should be referenced in the schemas shouldn't they?

Comment: so if I added the whole schemas it will have all the items? then there is no need to add each one, thank you for the help

Comment: You are missing the point.  You asked how to **find out** all of the namespaces that *could be* used by docx document.  The way to do that is to read / search the schemas, and extract the relevant URLs from them.

Comment: okay got it, sorry for the trouble